# Remove Dupes from FieldA where FieldB=X

Tags: mysql, duplicates

It turns out I have some duplicate records in a table where `FieldA=FieldA`.

The dupe I want to get rid of has `FieldB=Y`.

However, I don't want to just run

```
Delete from TableA where FieldB=Y
```

because I only want to delete `FieldB=Y` when it is a dupe. I suppose I need to construct some subquery from

```
having count(*) >1
```

but I'm unsure what that would look like.

Comment: Please share your table structure, sample data, and expected result.

Comment: Add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select FieldA
from TableA
group by FieldA
having count(*) > 1
```

returns all the duplicated `FieldA`s.
You can join the table to the above query in the `DELETE` statement:

```
delete a
from TableA a 
inner join (
  select FieldA
  from TableA
  group by FieldA
  having count(*) > 1
) t on t.FieldA = a.FieldA
where a.FieldB = Y
```